# Multiple AsyncTasks with sequential execution

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I know that Similar questions have been asked before but the solution to those questions will not work for me. The situation is that I have an Array of objects that are each getting sent to uploaded to the server via an asynctask. I need to send each one separately but each object in the list uses the same asynctask so calling task.execute in the onPostExecute() is not an option since that would cause it to infinitely call itself. I have tried something like so

```
for(each item in list){
    task.execute();
    while(task.getStatus() != android.os.AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
            //spin here and wait
    }
}
```

But when doing this it just spins for ever and never leaves the while loop.
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From AsyncTask docs:

> Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.

so if you are not >= HONEYCOMB, then maybe switch to use ExecutorService:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

Comment: So if I am greater than honeycomb what happens if I call.
task.execute();
task.execute();

Comment: It will execute serially, again from docs for API >= 11: SERIAL_EXECUTOR is default: `An Executor that executes tasks one at a time in serial order. This serialization is global to a particular process. `

Comment: Yea that worked I really wished I had known this. I just assumed that since async task starts a new thread that each new call would also create a new thread.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you change your architecture: Make the uploading async task take an array of files to upload and just loop through them?

If you really want to stay this way, just use a `lock` object.
Something like:

```
class MyAsyncClass extends AsyncTask{
   static Object lock = new Object();
   .......
   void doWork(){
   synchronized(lock) {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: I should point out that this does **not** ensure you, that the `doWork()` methods are executed in the order, they were called.

Comment: not the array, define something like `Object lockProvider;` which will do nothing, it will just serve as the object, to which you lock on.

Comment: oh ok and then just unlock it in the onPostexecute()?

Comment: Any chance you could provide some brief sudo code as to how this would work

Comment: @KBusc sure, take a look

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you should switch to Thread and [Executor service](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to do this. This will give you greater grip on switching between sequential and parallel execution of tasks.

With the help of ExecutorService(Actually a Threadpool manager).

- You can pass in the Tasks as runnable to executor service.
- You can define the number of threads to be used by executor Service (For your case, make it as 1).

Example :

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    service.submit(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

You can submit as many runnables to this and since the thread count is 1, it will get executed sequentially.

For communicating with UI, you can user Handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onPostExecute(){if(blahblah){
task.execute();
}
}
```

AKA put an if statement on task.execute so you have control..

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html), instead of an `AsyncTask` -- since launching multiple intents to the same `IntentService`will queue up the operations, so the Intent launched before will have to complete before the second `onHandleIntent(Intent)` will run.